# Rails: How to access images in Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm pretty new to Rails and have a little question:

How can i access images in Javascript? SCSS, ERB, ... have methods like "image_path", but i didn't find something similar for Javascript.

I need it to specify the image URLs for the firefly plugin:

```
$.firefly({images : ['???/1.jpg', '???/2.jpg'],total : 40});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your image in `/app/assets/images/` you can simply use

```
/assets/1.jpg
```

Similarly in css, you can use

```
url(/assets/1.jpg)
```

You can follow same thing when using in javascript.

```
$.firefly({images : ['/assets/1.jpg', '/assets/2.jpg'],total : 40});
```

Note: The above methods will cause problem when your rails app is in sub-directory. In that case use relative path. Asset pre-compilation will compile all assets in public/assets directory. so your structure may be like:

public
-assets
--images
---1.png
--javascripts
--stylesheets
---style.css

so from `style.css`, you can use relative path like `../images/1.png`

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to do this, I inserted the whatever image was required on the page under a **div#class** and set that class as hidden in my css. Then, in javascript, I could access the image from that div.

May not be ideal solution, but couldn't think of anything else because of asset pipeline.

Also, try accessing image from ./assets/image_name.jpg